# 2 trailing dots in URL crashing 403 Forbidden

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .htaccess, asp.net-mvc-4, url-rewriting

When any page on my site built in MVC has 2 trailing dots the page crashes and the user receives a 403 forbidden error.

**Example:**

This url will load correctly: `https://www.example.com/folder/`

When google tags a link with the google click id, sometimes the querystrings contain 2 trailing dots causing the site to crash.

`https://www.example.com/folder/?_gl=1*1c8z2ya*_g*ODcxNzE5OTQ1LjE2NM3MDUyNjc.*_ga_9HHLV212BL*MTY2MzcwNTI2Ny4xLjAuMTY2MzcwNTI2Ny4wLjAuMA..`

I have researched and cannot find that anyone else has had this issue in MVC.

I tried adding the following to the web.config but it did not fix the problem.

```cs
<system.web>    
  <httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"/>
</system.web>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why is this tagged `.htaccess`?

Comment: Because maybe it can be fixed with .htaccess? Looking for help, do you have any?

Comment: It's just that you reference `web.config` in your question, which is an IIS config file. `.htaccess` is an Apache config file. Two different web servers. Which web server are you using?

Comment: I am using Helicon Ape htaccess and I have a web.config file

Comment: Oh I see! FWIW, there's nothing you could _add_ to (Apache) `.htaccess` to resolve this, unless there is an existing rule that is explicitly blocking this type of request. (It sounds like an over zealous/incorrect security rule... query strings are not mapped to the filesystem and are not subject to the same restrictions as the rest of the URL-path.)

Comment: _Aside:_ It should be clarified in the question that you are referring to "Helicon Ape htaccess" and not "Apache htaccess" (which is strictly what the `.htaccess` tag refers to). There are some significant differences between the two.

Answer (score 0):

all good ? see I don't know what your server is but I think you can solve this with a url redirection rule, creating a rule where every call that enters https://www.example.com/folder/ has its queryString copied and redirected to the same url or even another one if possible internal to your server that will receive the data by doing this the server will ignore the dots at the end receiving the values ​​as real values ​​and not paths from a url to iis there is this way of doing it:

[Link Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module)